# MySQL INNER JOIN not returning correct result

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have a problem with a MySQL query right now and I can't figure it out... Hopefully someone can throw me a bone here :)

Ok so I have 2 databases:
user_(...,user_id, followers_count,...) 
post(...,user_id, artist_id,...)

and I want to calculate the potential followers reach for a specific artist (calculate the sum of the followers of all users talking about a specific artist)

Here is what I did so far... it returns a wrong value and I don't know why (the value returned is far too low).

```
SELECT SUM(followers_count) FROM
(SELECT u.user_id, u.followers_count, s.artist_id
FROM post s
INNER JOIN user_ u
ON s.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE s.artist_id=10
GROUP BY u.user_id) as T
```

The second problem is it takes aboout 15 minutes! to execute this query and I have indexes on u.user_id and s.user_id. But this problem may resolve itself if my query above is completely wrong ;) I really hope someone can help me I really don't get whats wrong.

Comment: You should do an `EXPLAIN` on your query to see how MySQL is executing it. That might help explain why it's going slowly. (Run your query, but precede the `SELECT` with `EXPLAIN`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without a subquery step. I haven't included the WHERE clause, though you could add that in easily enough

```
SELECT u.user_id, s.artist_id, SUM(u.followers_count) AS potent_reach
FROM post s
INNER JOIN user u ON u.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE s.artist_id=10
GROUP BY u.user_id, s.artist_id
```

With some small test data, it produces a correct sum.

If you do want to run the query with WHERE artist_id = 10 (or some value), you can drop the ORDER BY portion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, something similar to this should work:
(Disclaimer: I did not re-create your tables and populate them with data to test, so it may need a little tweaking).

```
SELECT
  s.artist_id, 
  sum(u.followers_count)
FROM post s
INNER JOIN user_ u
ON s.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE s.artist_id = 10
GROUP BY s.artist_id;
```

The use of a subquery with a 'Group By' clause is the most likely cause of the slow performance. It is best to avoid these whenever possible. When it is unavoidable, you'll want to add indexes to any columns used as part of a join to improve the performance.